# Conditional Sampling of Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, python-3.7

I have a Dataframe of Names, Sex, Ages of individuals:

I would like to create a new Dataframe by sampling a fixed number of samples such that the average age of the new DataFrame is the same as the original DataFrame.

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Var':['A','B','C','D','E'] , 'Ages' : [22,35,43,18,NaN]})

sample_df
Out[410]: 
  Var  Ages
0   A    22
1   B    35
2   C    43
3   D    18
4   E    NaN
```

I would like to sample only 3 rows such that the age of 'E' is equal to the mean of A,B,C,D

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: [link]https://ibb.co/yX8z074
Here is the screenshot of the data. The numbers represent the stores that are operational. You will notice that 2 separate weeks, only 2 stores were open. I would like to fill this data from the previous rows for that month such that the sales equal the mean of the previous data.

Comment: That information should go in your post, as text. Amongst other things, we need a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I have edited the post to have tried to describe as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an indefinite iteration using `while True` then `break` after needs are met but depending on the variability of your data, this may take some time to process. Below builds a list of 100-row samples and breaks after ten samples are achieved.

```
samples = []

while True:
   sample_df = df.sample(n = 100)

   if sample_df['Age'].mean() == df['Age'].mean():
      samples.append(sample_df)

   if len(samples) == 10:
      break
```